# Delete string between strings and replace with text plus counter

Tags: php, preg-replace, strpos

I want to remove all base64 images from a string

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0..="><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw1..=">...
```

and replace them with image1, image2 and so on.

```
<img src=" image1"><img src=" image2">...
```

So I am deleting the base64 part of the string and replacing it with "image" followed by the occurrence counter but it's not working so I get image1 all the time.

What can I do?
Thanks!!

This is my code so far:

```
    $replacement = "image";
    $stringResult= deleteBase64_andReplace("data:", "=", $replacement, $string);
    echo $stringResult;



function deleteBase64_andReplace($start, $end, $replacement, $string) {
    $count = 0;

    $pattern = '|' . preg_quote($start) . '(.*)' . preg_quote($end) . '|U'; 
 
    while (strpos($string, $start) !== false) { 
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement.++$count, $string); 

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but `preg_quote` should have `|` as its second parameter. `preg_quote($start, '|')`, second parameter is the delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `deleteBase64_andReplace` function with

```php
function deleteBase64_andReplace($start, $end, $replacement, $string) {
    $count = 0;
    $pattern = '|' . preg_quote($start, '|') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote($end, '|') . '|s'; 
    while (strpos($string, $start) !== false) { 
        return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use ($replacement, &$count) {
            return $replacement . ++$count;}, $string); 
    }
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/lHPoI). Output is `<img src="image1"><img src="image2">`.

Notes:

- `preg_replace` is replaced with `preg_replace_callback` to be able to make changes to `$count` when replacing the subsequent matches
- `preg_quote($start, '|') . '(.*?)' . preg_quote($end, '|')` now escapes the regex delimiter char, you chose `|` and it needs to be escaped, too
- I suggest omitting `U` flag and replace `.*` with `.*?` to make the regex more transparent

Comment: thanks a million, @Wiktor Stribiżew!! preg_replace_callback worked like a charm!